# Remove a selected index from text file

Tags: c#, selecteditem, selectedindexchanged

I have a listbox that displays lines from a text file. How could I make it so that I can click on an item from the listbox and remove it from the listbox and the text file

```
   private void Read()
    {
        string filePath = @"//Filepath";

        List<String> listOfDels = viewlist.listDeliveries();

        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(filePath, Encoding.Default))
        {
            while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
            {
                listOfDels.Add(streamReader.ReadLine());
                listBox1.Items.Clear();

                listBox1.Items.AddRange(listOfDels.ToArray());
            }
        }
    }

    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { //Remove line from txt file
    }
```

Comment: Why are you clearing `Items` each time you read a line?

Comment: to update it when I add more items

Comment: I think you're doing something horribly wrong. You're adding data to the list, then immediately clearing the list -- many, many times. Move the Clear and AddRange calls outside of your while loop.

Comment: I know it may be "technically" wrong but it's working for the time being. I just want to know how i'd remove a line by selected index

Comment: Also, you can just call `File.ReadAllLines(filePath)`.

Comment: Thanks Jon B, you're right that seems a lot tidier now!

Answer (score 1):

```
string tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();

using(var sr = new StreamReader("file.txt"))
{
using(var sw = new StreamWriter(tempFile))
{
    string line;

    while((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
         if(line != "removeme")
             sw.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
}

File.Delete("file.txt");
File.Move(tempFile, "file.txt");
```

Comment: This doesn't return an error, but it also doesn't do anything :S